# array.splice() gives error TypeError: arr.splice is not a function(…)

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var arr = document.querySelectorAll("a[href*='somestring']")
```

Returns what looks like an array in the console. Square braces [] and arr.length = 7.

Screen below. Why won't splice() work on my array?
[image]

Comment: [`.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) returns a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) which has no `.splice()` method

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The object returned from `querySelectorAll` is a `NodeList`, which is Array-*like*, yet not an actual array.

Try this to convert to an array:

```
[].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("a[href*='somestring']"));
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList

Answer (score 3):

*HTMLCollection* and *NodeList* objects do not have a `splice` method and do not inherit from `Array.prototype`.

Furthermore, you can't simply invoke a *splice* on them as they're not designed to be modified even though they are *Array-like*.

First, convert them to a true *Array*.

```
var arr = document.querySelectorAll("a[href*='somestring']"); // NodeList
arr = Array.prototype.slice.call(arr); // Array
arr.splice(2, 2); // splicing an Array
```

Answer (score 1):

`document.querySelectorAll("a[href*='somestring']")`  return an object not array.

try to convert it to an array:

```
var arr = document.querySelectorAll("a[href*='somestring']");

var a = [];
for(var i =0;i<arr.length ; i++){
a[i] = arr[i];
} 

a.splice()//now you can use a as an array
```